# Nvidia graphics card failed after upgrade to 10.10

Tags: 10.10, xorg, drivers, nvidia

After upgrading to 10.10, my system is unable to start in normal mode due to problems with graphics drivers. The laptop (hp dv9500) boots only in failsafe, low resolution graphics mode. Here's the message from the log:

```
[    67.427] (II) LoadModule: "nvidia"
[    67.427] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/extra-modules/nvidia_drv.so
[    67.428] (II) Module nvidia: vendor="NVIDIA Corporation"
[    67.428]    compiled for 4.0.2, module version = 1.0.0
[    67.428]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    67.431] (EE) NVIDIA: Failed to load the NVIDIA kernel module. Please check your
[    67.431] (EE) NVIDIA:     system's kernel log for additional error messages.
[    67.431] (II) UnloadModule: "nvidia"
[    67.431] (II) Unloading /usr/lib/xorg/extra-modules/nvidia_drv.so
[    67.431] (EE) Failed to load module "nvidia" (module-specific error, 0)
[    67.431] (EE) No drivers available.
```

What I tried to do already:

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*
sudo apt-get install nvidia-current
modprobe nvidia
FATAL: module nvidia not found.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download the proprietary drivers from [here](http://www.nvidia.com/object/unix.html). To run it, switch to runlevel 1 using `sudo init 1`, then log in from a console and run it with `sh NVidia*.run`.

When it asks whether to run `nvidia-xconfig`, select "Yes". Restart and you're good to go.

Note: you might need to run it again after every kernel update.

Comment: Thanks. This helped, but I had to upgrade kernel first, fix some bugs… This was a kind of adventure ;)